# join files and create index

Tags: linux, join, indexing

I want to join two files and index them in a new column as show below :

file A

```
apple     1 2 3 4 5 6
banana    3 2 4 4 5 6
orange    2 3 4 5 6 7
pear      2 4 5 6 3 5
```

file B

```
apple    1 3 4 5 6 7
grapes   4 5 6 4 3 6
melon    3 4 5 2 5 1
orange   2 4 5 6 7 8
```

I want to compare the two files based on first two columns, and output the common rows from file A and then add unique rows from both file A and file B and index them as shown below

output:

```
apple     1 2 3 4 5 6 both
orange    2 3 4 5 6 7 both
banana    3 2 4 4 5 6 fileA
pear      2 4 5 6 3 5  fileA
grapes   4 5 6 4 3 6   fileB
melon    3 4 5 2 5 1   fileB
```

Comment: what have you tried?  how do you want to tackle this?  linux commands/bash script?

Comment: Please document the algorithm requirements better.  What do the columns represent?  How did you arrive at "1 2 3 4 5 6" for the "apple" line given that that is **not** the contents in file B?

Comment: "1 2 3 4 5 6" for the "apple" arrive becoz the common contents come from file A whereas unique content comes from the respective files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`comm` compares two files and reports which lines occur in one, the other or both:

```
comm -2 <(cut -f1 -d' ' fileA | sort)
        <(cut -f1 -d' ' fileB | sort) \
  | sed $'/\t/{s/$/ both/;s/\t//};/ /!s/$/ fileA/' \
  | join -o1.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,1.2 - fileA \
  | sort -k8
cut -f1 -d' ' fileA \
  | grep -vFf- fileB \
  | sed 's/$/ fileB/'
```

As you can see, the pipeline is pretty complicated. If you plan to make changes to the code, consider moving to a more powerful language like Perl.